# PHP: can we access the property without declaration?

Tags: php

```
<?php
class A
    {
        public $attribute1;
        function operation1()
            {
                echo 'operation1';
            }
}
$a = new A();
$a->attribute3 = 10;
echo $a->attribute3;
```

when i run above script, It shows: `10`

Question:

There is no declaration of `attribute3` in  `class A`? why i can still use it `$a->attribute3 = 10;`?

Comment: Because that's how PHP works... Why *not*?

Comment: @hamish unfortunately....

Comment: @Orangepill unfortunately why?

Comment: coz you are setting the variable, and you are calling a variable. not a function

Comment: @Hamish because it lets me typo a property name without barking at me and silently introduces a bug instead of a helpful error message.

Comment: @orangepill, you can overwrite `__set()` if you don't want implicit declarations.

Comment: @Orangepill on the other hand, it means you can set object attributes without defining them in the class. Like you can with Javascript or Python. So, pros & cons.

Comment: @Hamish Javascript it's understandable since there is no concept of a class

Comment: @Hamish I would be a dirty liar if I said I haven't successfully used this "feature" of php without issue but 99% of those cases I could have produced the same results by just not being lazy.

Comment: @Orangepill re JS: you can modify any attribute of an object's prototype. My point was, OP seems suprised that it's possible, but it's common in many langauges.

Comment: While you can do this... Have you ever heard about `data encapsulation`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Hamish said ... because that is how PHP works.

Just like you can say:

```
$a = "hello";
```

and create a property in a function's scope or in the global scope you can use

```
$obj->a = "hello";
```

to create a property in the $obj instance's scope.

If this is undesired behavior you can throw an exception using the __get and __set magic methods.

```
class A{
   public $property1;

   public function __get($property){
          throw new Exception($property." does not exist in ".__CLASS__);
   }
   public function __set($property, $value){
          throw new Exception($property." does not exist in ".__CLASS__);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short: *because you can*.

PHP lets you define object attributes without declaring them in the class.

It's not an uncommon feature, e.g. python:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass
foo = Foo()
foo.bar = "Hi"
print foo.bar  # "Hi"
```